# javascript library that can parse spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, spreadsheet

I'm building a web app that lets user upload a spreasheet file (.xlsx) and fills a table with its contents and displays the user, but I need a parser that can take that data and convert it to a json file or an array of arrays.

Comment: Can you save the xlsx as a csv file? If so, your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-xlsx is the library you're looking for:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-xlsx

NB: If you need to parse in front-end, you may use Browserify to convert the library to an embeddable script.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, for now parsing front-end.

Answer (score 1):

http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/ has a demo of their library that does all this

And the github repo https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: This is a very helpful, going to try this library! Thank you!